# Scrool Mouse Acompanhando linhas, com css e jquery

Tags: jquery, css

Preciso fazer com que de acordo que o scrool do mouse for rodando para baixo, vai acompanhando uma linha ao lado, isso eu consegui fazer, como mostro no link abaixo

[Clique aqui para ver o exemplo](http://187.23.65.93/3dmind/texte.html)

Minha dificuldade esta quando abre a página e já aparece **duas Linhas**, como eu posso fazer, para que abra o site e  **apareça apenas primeira linha**?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var count;
  $('#servicos ul li.bloco').each(function( index ) {
    count = index;
  });

  $(window).scroll(function (event) {

    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    var item = $('#servicos ul').offset().top;
    if( (scroll+400) > item ){
      animSvg( $('.svg') );    
    }

    $('#servicos ul li.bloco').each(function( index ) {
      if( index < (count+1) ){
        var item = $(this).offset().top;
        var anim = $(this).find('.svg-lista');
        if( (scroll+200) > item ){
          var ativo = $('.label_serv a').children('li').eq(index);
          $('.label_serv a li').removeClass('active');
          ativo.addClass('active');


          animSvg( anim );    
        }
      }

    });

  });

});

function animSvg(obj){
  var val = obj.data('to');
  var dist = obj.scrollTop();

  obj.animate({
    'stroke-dasharray': val
  }, 1000, function() {
    /*fim*/
  });
}


function scrollCustom(id){
    var offset = $('#header_titulo').height();
    $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:$('#' + id).position().top + offset}, 'slow');
}
```

Comment: Seria legal você editar a sua pergunta trazendo o código que você desenvolveu e está com dificuldades para alterar.

Comment: @LeandroAngelo está ali amigo

Comment: Qual o nome do plugin que controla essas linhas?

Comment: @ÐvÐ <script src="js/jquery.stellar_custom.min.js"></script>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pode fazer assim:

Após o `$(document).ready(function(){...`, inclua um *flag* `var mPrimeiro = false;`:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   var mPrimeiro = false;
...
```

Onde tem:

```
if( (scroll+200) > item ){
```

Altere para:

```
if( scroll+mValor > item ){
```

E finalmente, inclua este código antes da linha acima:

```
!mPrimeiro ? (mValor = item-1, mPrimeiro = true) : mValor = 200;
```

Comment: Muito bom , deu certinho, obrigado

Comment: @WagnerMartinsBodyboard Valeu!!